# What is the best way to backup and restore a CentOS 7 server, using rsnapshot?

Tags: centos, backup, rsync, backup-restoration, rsnapshot

I recently made a backup of a `CentOS 7` server using `rsnapshot - version 1.3.1` and `rsync -version 3.0.9`

I made a few changes to the `rsnapshot.conf` file, which are listed below.

I uncommented the following lines:

```
#cmd_cp       /usr/bin/cp
#cmd_ssh      /usr/bin/ssh
#cmd_du       /usr/bin/du
#link_dest    0
```

And I added the following lines:

```
backup        /var            localhost/
backup        /srv            localhost/
backup        /root           localhost/
```

After running the command `rsnapshot hourly`, I was left with a copy of the following directories, as expected:

`/etc` `/home` `/root` `/srv` `/usr` `/var`

I'm a PHP developer so what I did next will probably hurt all the sysadmins out there.

To test the backup I created a fresh install of `CentOS 7` on another server and replaced the 6 directories mentioned above with the 6 from my backup, using the commands:

```
rsync -av /backup/etc /etc
rsync -av /backup/home /home
rsync -av /backup/root /root
rsync -av /backup/srv /srv
rsync -av /backup/usr /usr
rsync -av /backup/var /var
```

The directories were successfully overwritten and that was the last time I ever saw that server. It failed to boot after that.

I receive these 4 errors during the failed boot process:

```
[FAILED] Failed to listen on LVM2 metadata daemon socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, sn...ogress polling.
[FAILED] Failed to listen on Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs.
[FAILED] Failed to start Activation of DM RAID sets.
```

So my questions are:

What is the correct procedure to restore a server from a backup made using rsnapshot?

Are there directories that I haven't included in the backup that I should have?

And lastly, which directories or sub-directories, once replaced, are likely to be the ones that caused the server not to boot?

A bit of info that might help:

The server I attempted to backup has 2 users and Apache, PHP and PostgreSQL installed. It also has everything that would be installed as a result of running the following command:

`yum –y groupinstall "Base" "Development Libraries" "Development Tools"`

Thanks in advance.